# Plotting a dataframe (pandas) in pycharm, not displaying

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pycharm

My data looks like the following when I `print` it.

`print data`

```
                  A               B
2014-04-04      0.000000       0.000000
2014-06-11      0.013416      -0.049643
2014-12-22      0.175361      -0.114184
2014-03-25     -0.160409       0.208127
2014-11-03      0.168943      -0.157301
2014-06-16     -0.130902       0.109455
```

`pd.scatter_matrix(data, diagonal='kde', figsize=(10, 10))`

where `pd = import pandas as pd`

There are no errors thrown but i do not see the chart anywhere(?).

The data is "chartable" as matplotlib.pyplot works. Matplotlib is only displayed when I call `matplotlib.pyplot.plt.show()`.

I am assuming the plot is not being shown, but then how do i "show" it?

Edit:
I am working from [this](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/twiecki/financial-analysis-python-tutorial/blob/master/1.%20Pandas%20Basics.ipynb) example.

thanks

Comment: You can post and accept if you already solved the problem.

Comment: Cannot respond to your own answer for a certain period of time. I unfortunately found the answer shortly after posting.

Comment: @Alex if you have some time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042603/pandas-df-corr-returns-nan-despite-data-fed-having-populated-data

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`plt.show()` must be called where `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`