# pandas df.corr() returns NaN despite data fed having populated data

Tags: python, pandas

My data looks like the following:

`print data`

```
                   A                B 
2014-04-04        163.24         191.77
2014-06-11        165.43         182.25
2014-12-22        194.44         161.44
2014-03-25        163.25         195.04
2014-11-03        190.83         164.36
2014-06-16        165.85         182.35
2014-11-24        190.07         162.15
2014-05-21        159.35         186.39
2015-01-21        177.15         152.09
2014-08-28        177.65         192.00
2014-02-19        163.26         182.95
2014-05-12        159.55         192.57
2014-07-09        164.67         188.42
2015-02-26        192.20         160.87
2014-10-14        178.70         183.80
2014-07-16        170.47         192.36
2014-01-21        173.20         188.43
2014-06-03        161.80         184.37
2014-03-17        166.84         185.81
2014-08-11        172.46         187.47
2015-01-07        187.28         155.05
2014-05-29        160.74         183.76
2015-02-11        187.65         158.20
2014-02-27        165.38         185.27
2015-01-05        188.34         159.51
2014-07-01        166.81         186.35
2015-02-18        188.67         162.19
2014-04-03        166.09         192.69
2014-10-06        187.48         189.04
2014-12-29        196.19         160.51
```

When I try to call `data.corr()` I receive back all `NaN`. I tested this in excel, and the correlation is indeed able to be calculated.

Any idea why this might be the case?

I am happy to post more but i am unsure what would help.

```
print data.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 298 entries, 2014-04-04 to 2014-01-29
Data columns (total 2 columns):
A     298 non-null float64
B    298 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)None



print data.describe()
              A                B
    count    298.000000     298.000000
    mean     175.152886     178.596242
    std       11.490668      13.709316
    min      152.720000     151.410000
    25%      165.502500     162.655000
    50%      175.480000     184.330000
    75%      185.085000     189.692500
    max      196.890000     197.770000


print pd.version
0.14.1
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the output of `df.info()`, `df.describe()`, and `print(pd.__version__)`?

Comment: Does this help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854878/correlation-between-columns-in-dataframe

Comment: @DSM posted. Need more chars for length limit.

Comment: @denvar i took a look and both of my standard deviations are valid for the caluclation.

Comment: Can you show the actual NaN results?  Also wouldn't hurt to update to 15.2 (and 16.0 is coming in a few days btw).  Probably won't help, but unless you have a good reason not to, might as well get the latest version.  You could also try doing this with ```np.corrcoef()``` just to see if anything changes or if you get an informative error message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jason, Using the sample data it works fine for me.

```
data.corr()
    A   B
A   1.000000    -0.779864
B   -0.779864   1.000000
```

I noticed in your data.info() there is a 'None' tacked on to dtypes. When I load your sample data I get

```
data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 30 entries, 2014-04-04 to 2014-12-29
Data columns (total 2 columns):
A     30 non-null float64
B     30 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
```

I imagine what's causing that 'None' is causing your problem.

Hope this helps [wish I could leave as a comment but don't have the reputation yet!]

Comment: I noticed that as well. How do I go about solving that?

Comment: Do you get the same problem on the subset of data you have displayed?  I wonder if you just have something corrupted in the data somehow.  Ideally, for troubleshooting it helps if you can whittle data down to the smallest size possible that preserves the problem and ideally create the data in the code (obv not possible if you read in the data from somewhere else and THAT is actually the source of the problem.

Comment: @EngineeredE: this was the issue. Once i `float()`-ed my data, it worked perfectly.