# Why does pandas.Series.corr return Nan whereas numpy or scipy compute a number?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, correlation

I try to compute correlation between two pandas series. This is what I get from numpy or scipy :

```
scipy.stats.pearsonr(xfarines["400"].values, yfarines["PROTREF"].values)


(0.71564870605278108, 2.9185934338775347e-23)


pd.np.corrcoef(xfarines["400"].values, yfarines["PROTREF"].values)


array([[ 1.        ,  0.71564871],
   [ 0.71564871,  1.        ]])
```

But this is what pandas gives me :

```
s = xfarines["400"]
s.corr(yfarines["PROTREF"])


nan
```

Looking at this question, 
[pandas df.corr() returns NaN despite data fed having populated data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042603/pandas-df-corr-returns-nan-despite-data-fed-having-populated-data)
I check if the dtypes are ok and it seems it is :

```
s.describe()

count    140.000000
mean       0.304078
std        0.057225
min        0.197300
25%        0.250300
50%        0.318500
75%        0.346850
max        0.408600
Name: 400, dtype: float64


yfarines["PROTREF"].describe()

count    140.000000
mean      12.619143
std        2.547644
min        7.600000
25%       10.975000
50%       12.100000
75%       14.590000
max       18.200000
Name: PROTREF, dtype: float64
```

Thus I do not understand where the problem comes from ?

Comment: what is the index for the dataframes? are they aligned?

Comment: I look at closely to the index. They are strings. Actually, in `yfarines` there was several whitespace at the end. By cleaning this whitespace, `s.corr` return the same value as numpy or scipy !
Is there a way to clean this whitespace at the time you read the csv ?

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13386025/6904813) does exactly this

Answer (score 0):

Strange that you mention numpy (v 1.8.0) but use the scipy import which may be different.  This is what numpy does

```
>>> a
array([[ 3.00000000,  0.17157288],
       [ 3.00000000,  1.58578644],
       [ 3.00000000,  3.00000000],
       [ 3.00000000,  4.41421356],
       [ 3.00000000,  5.82842712]])
>>> np.corrcoef(a[:,0], a[:,1],rowvar=0, bias=0, ddof=None)
array([[ nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  1.00000000]]
```

Perhaps people with newer version can confirm what it returns, but at least for a vertical line's points that is what is given.
For a horizontal line's points you get

```
>>> b = np.array([a[:,1],a[:,0]]).T
>>> b
array([[ 0.17157288,  3.00000000],
       [ 1.58578644,  3.00000000],
       [ 3.00000000,  3.00000000],
       [ 4.41421356,  3.00000000],
       [ 5.82842712,  3.00000000]])
>>> np.corrcoef(b[:,0], b[:,1],rowvar=0, bias=0, ddof=None)
array([[ 1.00000000,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan]])
```