# Pandas df.corr() returns nan when np.corrcoef() returns values unless NaNs in dataset

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, dataframe, correlation

My question is very similar to [pandas df.corr() returns NaN despite data fed having populated data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042603/pandas-df-corr-returns-nan-despite-data-fed-having-populated-data) but the solutions given in that do not work for me  as my data `dtypes: float64(2)` and `describe()` returns `non-null float64`.

I am using pandas: 0.19.0 with python 2.7

I have two dataframes, with a column of non-null float data called `WindSp_mean`. I create these two dateframes by looping through a set of specified dates in the master dataset to create a `df_turbine0` and `df_turbine1` for each timestep based on a unique identifier in in another column.

for each timestep I want to calculate a pearson correlation coefficient between the `WindSp_mean` column in the two dataframes. Some dataframes may contain nans so I want to use `df.corr()` to find the pearson correlation between their `WindSp_mean`columns rather than `np.corrcoef()`

testing `df.corr()` by comparing the `WindSp_mean` in the first df with itself, gives the expected answer of 1.

`pcorr1 = df_turbine0['WindSp_mean'].corr(df_turbine0['WindSp_mean'])`

trying this with the same column both dataframes

`pcorr2 = df_turbine0['WindSp_mean'].corr(df_turbine1['WindSp_mean'])`

returns nan despite there being 144 non-null floats in both columns.

if I use `np.corrcoef()` with the same values used.`

```
turbine0_windspeed = df_turbine0['WindSp_mean']
turbine1_windspeed = df_turbine1['WindSp_mean']
pcorr1 = np.corrcoef(turbine1_windspeed, turbine0_windspeed)
```

I get results with values close to 1 for all timesteps in my loop until some nans break the code with `ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly`.

[image]

Sample data for df_turbine1, df_turbine0

```
        datetime    WindSp_max  WindSp_mean
218705  28/12/2017 18:40    15.4    10.39798
218706  28/12/2017 18:50    14.1    10.49598
218707  28/12/2017 19:00    13.01   9.025653
218708  28/12/2017 19:10    13.68   9.276702
218709  28/12/2017 19:20    14.02   9.125614
218710  28/12/2017 19:30    12.51   8.900918
218711  28/12/2017 19:40    12.76   9.177135
218712  28/12/2017 19:50    12.84   9.082051
218713  28/12/2017 20:00    12.17   8.60314

        datetime    WindSp_max  WindSp_mean
109120  28/12/2017 18:40    13.93   11.08517
109121  28/12/2017 18:50    13.77   10.16184
109122  28/12/2017 19:00    12.93   10.20069
109123  28/12/2017 19:10    14.19   10.64296
109124  28/12/2017 19:20    13.93   10.50484
109125  28/12/2017 19:30    13.77   10.60769
109126  28/12/2017 19:40    14.02   10.81324
109127  28/12/2017 19:50    14.35   10.45523
109128  28/12/2017 20:00    13.68   10.32253
```

for this timestep `print df_turbine0.isnull().sum()` returns no nan values in either `df_turbine0` or `df_turbine1`. Each `df` contains 144 non-null values and `df_pcorr1` is 288 rows. Whenever there is a value in column 1, there is a nan in column 2 and vice versa

I assume that because `df_turbine0` and `df_turbine1` are a subset of the same dataset, they are carrying the indexing from the original df, which might be causing errors.

However, changing the index to datetime or resetting it didn't make any difference to the calculation of `pcorr1()` or to the Index.

```
df_turbine0.set_index(['datetime'])

df_turbine0.reset_index()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You run `df_pcorr1 = pd.concat([turbine1_windspeed, turbine0_windspeed], axis=1)`, which concatenates two dataframes (or series), probably both of length 1 in your case. Why do you compare that to a call to `np.corrcoeff`? Concatenating dataframes is different than calculating a correlating coefficient. What do I miss?

Comment: Very good point! You missed it because I hadn't included all of the code. Edited now to include the lines I am comparing with `np.corrcoeff()`, `pcorr1 = df_pcorr1.corr()`

Comment: Please include sample data in body of post (not as [image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451)) and be sure such a sample is enough to [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/1422451) your NaN issue on `corr`.

Comment: What do your concatenated dataframes look like? e.g., `df_pcorr1` and friends? These should be short enough to list fully in your question.

Comment: (Aside: your code could be much shorter, since you've essentially copy-pasted the same code four times, instead of using an appropriate loop. I mention it, because it would also make the question clearer, that is, not blurred by lots of repeated code. Alternatively, just remove 2 turbines from your example code, so that your left with at least one good (no NaNs) and one bad set of concatenated dataframes. Technically, we don't even need `turbine5= turbine_list[5];
    df_turbine5 = df_24hour[df_24hour['StationName'].str.contains(turbine5)]` and friends, just the value of `df_turbine5`.)

Comment: Agreed, that was one of the worst questions (with pretty terrible code) i have written in a long time. Edited to show a more succint question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an indexing error. All of the smaller `df_turbine` came from the same original Dataframe and the index was kept. This was fixed by resetting the index using `inplace =True`

`df_turbine1.reset_index(drop = True,  inplace=True)`